# Scala issue in Eclipse: error while loading javax.jws.soap

Tags: eclipse, scala, soap

I'm getting this error (shown in Problems view) in Eclipse (3.7) when building my Scala project using Scala IDE plugin (scala version 2.10).

```
error while loading javax.jws.soap., class file  
'C:\jdk1.7\jre\lib\rt.jar(javax/jws/soap/SOAPBinding$Use.class)'
 is broken (class java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException/addChild
 inapplicable for <none>)

Location:Unknown
Type: Scala Problem
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks.

Jan

Comment: I faced similar issue today, but with `jdk1.6` and `sbt`. Have you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: Nope _____________________

Comment: It was issue with java compiler. Occasionally it was aliased to java 1.4

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: It was environment with multiple `jdk`s; `java` executable was aliased to 1.6 version (as expected), but `javac` executable pointed to some custom 1.4 eclipse-flavored version of compiler. So, I think we both faced eclipse compiler bug, mentioned in [SI-7002](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7002)